# Show that monotonicity directly follows countable additivity

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

In these notes http://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math776/Spring11/776s11lec03_notes.pdf it says countable additivity implies monotonicity of measure

I want to show that $\mu(\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E_k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mu(E_k)$ implies that $A \subseteq B$ then $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$

**This is my solution can someone check if it is right?**

Ok so obviously $E_1 \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E_k$

And we know that $\mu(E_1) + \mu(E_2) + \ldots +  \ldots = \mu(\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E_k)$

Then take out all these $\mu(E_k), k \geq 2$  guys

$\mu(E_1) \leq \mu(\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty E_k)$

QED!

Is this proof correct? Can someone offer/direct me to an alternative proof for me to compare? Thanks

Comment: You may make a simpler argument. Also I'm pretty sure countable additivity requires the sets $E_k$ to be disjoint, i.e. $E_k\cap E_j=\emptyset$ for all $k\neq j$. Anyway, Let $A\subset B$. Write $B$ as a disjoint union, and then use countable additivity and the nonnegativity of the measure. For example $B=(B\setminus A)\cup A$, so that $\mu(B)=\mu(B\setminus A) +\mu(A)$.....etc (lemme know if you cannot finish this argument and I'll write it up as an answer)

Comment: I might ask you to explain what "so take out all these $\mu (E_k),k\geq 2$" actually means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that you want to show monotonicity for arbitrary sets, not just an instantiated union $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n$. Instead, I think that you want to *use* the countable additivity condition since is true *for all* disjoint unions, rather than first defining an arbitrary countable union.

Instead:  Let $A \subseteq B$ be  a proper subset. Then $B=A \bigcup (B-A)$.
But then $A \bigcap (B-A)=\emptyset$ so we can utilize countable additivity.

If $B=A$ we are done, since $m(A)=m(B)$.

So wlog let $A \subset B$ be a proper subset. By countable additivity:

Then $m(B)=m(A \bigcup (B-A))=m(A)+m(B-A)$. Since $m(B-A) \geq 0$, it follows that $m(A) \leq m(B)$.

Your proof is not non-salvageable, you would just have to say more about why your proof applies to sets in general.

**edit** 
First we need a small lemma: $m(\emptyset)=0$. We first note that measure is nonnegative.

Then: let $A_i=\emptyset$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then 
$$m(\emptyset)=m\left(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i\right)=\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} m(A_i)=m(\emptyset)+m(\emptyset)+m(\emptyset)+...$$ If $m(\emptyset) \neq 0$, then the sum will diverge. We conclude that $m(\emptyset)=0$.

**now**:countable additivity $\implies$ finite additivity.

Let $\bigcup_{1}^{n} E_n$ be a finite union of disjoint sets. Define $E_{k}=\emptyset$ for all $k>n$.

Then $$m(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} m(E_n)=\sum_{1}^{n}m(E_n)+\sum_{n+1}^{\infty} m(E_n)=\sum_{1}^{n}m(E_n)+m(\emptyset)=\sum_{1}^{n}m(E_n)$$

Comment: I guess retrospectively my main argument works without excluding the $B=A$ case, but I'll leave it for clarity's sake.

Comment: Yes I thought about your approach which is correct of course but then I would had to show countable additivity implies finite additivity

Comment: I edited, I hope that it makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: As a final aside: The reason that the sum cannot diverge is again because of countable additivity. Say, any set of finite measure $\bigcup$ an uncountable union of empty sets must still have finite measure.

Comment: There is some chaos in that countable additivity $\Rightarrow$ finite additivity part but the intention is clear

Comment: It is pretty much tacking on a bunch of empty sets

Comment: @Andres:  I'm terribly sorry to be a stickler (I had referred to this proof a couple times), but I think the placement of your $m$'s needs adjusted in both the lemma and the proposition that countable additivity implies finite additivity above - I fully understand your entire proof conversely.  You need a sum of measures, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, in the lemma's proof, and the very last line has the measure of a "sum" of sets in the right-hand side of the first equality as well as the measure of the sum of measures in the right-hand side of second equality, etc. Great proof overall however.

Comment: @procore, im away from my computer, but I see the exact problem, I think they are copy paste typos, as evidenced by my measure of a measure in the last line! If you'd like to make the edits, feel free. Otherwise, I'll do it in the next day or so. Thanks.

Comment: @Procore the deed is done.

Comment: @AndresMejia:  Sorry for my delay as well, and for being a stickler again, but I very much liked your arguments, and I knew what you were getting at overall; I guess I was also accounting for those much newer to measure theory, and I figured it was helpful to point everything out to minimize any sort of confusion, should any arise. Thank you for the elegant proof!